# Ошибка при добавлении переменной в контейнер - No context actions available at this location

Tags: java, swing, maven, jframe, apache-poi

При попытке добавить переменную в контейнер, получаю сообщение:

> No context actions available at this location.

А в заголовке не написано "Анкета".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ContactForm form = new ContactForm();
        form.setVisible(true);

    }
}

public class ContactForm extends JFrame {
    public ContactForm(){

        super("Анкета");
        super.setBounds(400, 400, 500, 250);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = super.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 2, 2));

        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Назовите ваше имя");
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Сколько вам лет");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(input);
        >вот здесь ошибка при попытке добавить переменную 
        container.add(name);
        container.add(age);

        System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Comment: И не сможешь т.к. метод `add` принимает на вход: `Component` / `PopupMenu` / `Component, Object` / `Component, int`, `String(name), Component` / `Component, Object, int`

Comment: Спасибо большое, не подскажете, каким методом я могу воспользоваться

Comment: А какая у тебя цель?

Comment: Можно обернуть в JLabel, если нужно строку текстом вывести.

Comment: Подключил JLabel , спасибо за ответы